# Required tag missing error on MarketDataRequest query

Tags: quickfix

I have a `FIX44.MarketDataRequest` query based on **Trade Client** example from [QuickFIX-n example applications](http://www.quickfixn.org/tutorial/example-applications). But I can't manage to get something useful from the server with this query. I always get the error `Required tag missing` for this query.
Here is my code:

```
MDReqID mdReqID = new MDReqID("MARKETDATAID");
SubscriptionRequestType subType = new SubscriptionRequestType(SubscriptionRequestType.SNAPSHOT);
MarketDepth marketDepth = new MarketDepth(0);

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup marketDataEntryGroup = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
marketDataEntryGroup.Set(new MDEntryType(MDEntryType.BID));

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup symbolGroup = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
symbolGroup.Set(new Symbol("EUR/USD"));

QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest message = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest(mdReqID, subType, marketDepth);
message.AddGroup(marketDataEntryGroup);
message.AddGroup(symbolGroup);
```

Here is the generated outbound application level message (ToApp):

```
8=FIX.4.49=15835=V34=249=order.DEMOSUCD.12332150=DEMOSUSD52=20141223-07:02:33.22656=demo.fxgrid128=DEMOSUSD262=MARKETDATAID263=0264=0267=1269=0146=155=EUR/USD10=232
```

Here is the received ToAdmin message:

```
8=FIX.4.49=14935=334=249=demo.fxgrid52=20141223-07:02:36.51056=order.DEMOSUCD.12332157=DEMOSUSD115=DEMOSUSD45=258=Required tag missing371=265372=V373=110=136
```

If I understand correctly the pair `371=265` (RefTagID=MDUpdateType) after `258=Required tag missing` indicates which tag is missing, .i.e. is missing `MDUpdateType`. But this is strange because this tag is optional for `MarketDataRequest`.

**UPDATE**

Here is my FIX config file:

```
[DEFAULT]
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
CheckLatency=N

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=demo.fxgrid
SenderCompID=XXX
SenderSubID=YYY
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=ZZZ
SocketConnectHost=X.X.X.X
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
Username=AAA
Password=BBB
```

Comment: I would check your FIX config file to check if 265 is set to a compulsory tag.

Comment: @DumbCoder which setting (from FIX config) can be used to specify mandatory tags?

Comment: `DataDictionary=FIX44.xml` Check `FIX44.xml` file. This file will have the mandatory and the fields possible in messages.

Comment: @DumbCoder here comes the strange part... in `FIX44.xml` inside the definition of `MarketDataRequest` message we have: `<field name="MDUpdateType" required="N" />` i.e. it is not mandatory.

Comment: Check the spec on the server side. They probably have it as Y. Your FIX44.xml is fine.

Comment: @DumbCoder how can I check the spec on the server side? using QuickFIX or technical support service?

Comment: Is the server your counterparty's server ? Then check your counteparty FIX specification which you might have agreed on. Basic idea is check the FIX specifications used by the acceptor.

Comment: @RaduDumbrăveanu hi, did you solve it? why did the problem arise? How did you solve it? I am facing the same problem.